# compiz keeps quitting in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gui, window-manager, compiz

Just executed

```
$  compiz --replace
$  cccsm
```

And it worked for 2 minutes while I configured some stuff (like Wobbly Windows) then `compiz` all of a sudden freaks out and quits. I have to reboot. What's going wrong?

Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: FWIW, 11.10 uses Compiz by default, you shouldn't have to start it manually. (Unity is just a Compiz plugin.)

Comment: @grawity that's weird... if i don't do that then nothing works